# Django - Filtering inside of get_context_data

Tags: python, django

Using class-based views in Django, I'm having a problem filering inside of a DetailView.

What i would like to get is a list of all movies in a specific genre ie: `Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=genre_id)`.

```
class GenreView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Genre
    template_name = 'movies/genre.html'
    context_object_name = 'this_genre'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(GenreView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'all_movies': Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=pk),
        'all_genres': Genre.objects.all()
    })
    return context
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handler
s\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handler
s\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generi
c\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generi
c\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generi
c\detail.py", line 118, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
  File "C:\Users\admin\trailers\movies\views.py", line 43, in get_context_data
    'all_movies': Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=pk),
NameError: name 'pk' is not defined
```

When I tried replacing `Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=pk)` with `Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=kwargs['pk'])` I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handler
s\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handler
s\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generi
c\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generi
c\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generi
c\detail.py", line 118, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
  File "C:\Users\admin\trailers\movies\views.py", line 43, in get_context_data
    'all_movies': Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=kwargs['pk']),
KeyError: 'pk'
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show me your url for this class GenreView(generic.DetailView) view??

Comment: url(r'^genre/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.GenreView.as_view(), name='genre')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `kwargs` parameter passed to `get_context_data` doesn't contain the primary key value of the object. You can get it from `self.kwargs` though:

```
Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Furthermore, you will see `self.object` *(which is the the `Genre` instance fetched)* is present and accessible when you are inside `get_context_data`, so you can use that in order to do the following as well:

```
Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=self.object)
```

Comment: Both work perfectly, although I prefer `Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=self.object)` thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
  'all_movies': Movie.objects.all().filter(genre=pk)
```

you literally haven't defined pk. You need to assign the pk to the pk variable first.

Also you don't need to include all:

```
Movie.objects.filter(genre=pk)
```